# Find cell based on a property

Tags: vba

I need to find a cell into a worksheet but I'd like to avoid looking for a string.

The problem I have is that the worksheet will be edited by my client. If ever he decides to write the string I'm looking for before the good one, the app will crash.

```
Sub FindSpecificCell()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TP 1")
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim rangeFinal As Range
    Set monRange = ws.Range("A:AJ")

    Set rangeFinal = myRange.Find("Description du test")
    Debug.Print " "
    Debug.Print "Looking for ""Description du test"" in TP 1 "
    Debug.Print "column : " & rangeFinal.Column
    Debug.Print "row : " & rangeFinal.Row

End Sub
```

Is there a way to insert a kind of property inside the cell in order to be sure that I'm working on the good one?

Comment: You can give the cell a custom name and get its value with Range("myCell") or [myCell]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't associated properties with a specific cell directly, but you can use properties with the worksheet to store this information.  I've used a couple methods like this before:

```
'Set the provided value of the custom property with the provided name in the provided sheet.
Private Sub SetCustomPropertyValue(InSheet As Worksheet, WithPropertyName As String, WithValue As Variant)
    Dim objCP As CustomProperty
    Dim bolFound As Boolean
    bolFound = False 'preset.

    For Each objCP In InSheet.CustomProperties
        'if this property's name is the one whose value is sought...
        If (StrComp(objCP.Name, WithPropertyName, vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
            objCP.Value = WithValue
            bolFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'if the property didn't already exist on the sheet, add it.
    If (Not bolFound) Then Call InSheet.CustomProperties.Add(WithPropertyName, WithValue)
End Sub

'Return the value of the custom property with the provided name in the provided sheet.
Private Function GetCustomPropertyValue(InSheet As Worksheet, WithPropertyName As String) As Variant
    Dim objCP As CustomProperty
    GetCustomPropertyValue = Empty

    For Each objCP In InSheet.CustomProperties
        'if this property's name is the one whose value is sought...
        If (StrComp(objCP.Name, WithPropertyName, vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
            GetCustomPropertyValue = objCP.Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Then you can do something like this to write and read back values:

```
Sub test()
    Dim strPropName As String
    strPropName = "MyRange_" & Selection.Address
    Dim strWhatIWantToStore As String
    strWhatIWantToStore = "Here's what I want to store for this range"

    Call SetCustomPropertyValue(ActiveSheet, strPropName, strWhatIWantToStore)
    MsgBox GetCustomPropertyValue(ActiveSheet, strPropName)
End Sub
```